# My Chebyshev filter band pass filter produce tiny values

Tags: filter, signal-processing, band-pass

I am using a Chebyshev band pass filter:

```
Fs = 50
wc =[0.1,0.9] 
Ap = 0.025
filter_order=2
z, p = signal.cheby1(filter_order,Ap, wc, 'bandpass',analog=True)
```

The values in the resulting vectors are tiny and a good portion is Nan. Should I try to switch the filter or I should try some DSP tirck to make this filter works under the same parameters?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what programming language and library you are using.  Have you tried using the filter delivered by the library method?  Maybe it is correct despite looking funny.

Comment: Going to need more info on this question, what values are tiny? You may be using constraints that make it hard for the tool to come up with a solution.

Comment: @JRE this is python, using scipy.signal; however, that's an IIR, so stability might be a problem, but: yeaaah, there's a bit too much information missing to actually help. "Tiny" is not a problem at all (this is all floating-point)

Answer (score 1):

That's not what I get:

```
import scipy.signal as sp
w = [0.1, 0.9]
A = 0.025
N = 2
z, p = sp.cheby1(N, A, w, 'bandpass', analog=True)
z,p
(array([4.21159721, 0.        , 0.        ]), array([1.        , 2.79418562, 4.40373663, 0.25147671, 0.0081    ]))
```

This gives you a transfer funcion in \$s\$:

$$H(s)=\dfrac{4.2116s^2}{s^4+2.794s^3+4.404s^2+0.2515s+0.0081} \tag{1}$$

(which means your `Fs` and that `analog=True` are mutually exclusive), and if you plot it you'll see a Chebyshev-like response with passband edges at 0.1 Hz and 0.9 Hz:

[image: result]

Did you use the transfer function in the \$z\$ domain? If you want a digital filter, then you should use a different command:

```
z, p = sp.cheby1(N, A, w, 'bandpass')
z,p
(array([ 0.83936287,  0.        , -1.67872575,  0.        ,  0.83936287]), array([ 1.00000000e+00, -2.22044605e-15, -1.65663270e+00,  2.15105711e-15,
        7.10496246e-01]))
```

You can ignore the `e-15` terms, they're numeric residuals, and you can construct your transfer function as:

$$H(z)=\dfrac{0.84-1.678z^{-2}+0.84z^{-4}}{1-1.6566z^{-2}+0.7105z^{-4}} \tag{2}$$

But the plot will show passband edges at `0.1*f=5 Hz` and `0.9*f=45 Hz`, which is probably not what you wanted:

[image: z-domain]

Comment: it seems that I get better reuslts if I use lfiltred instead but do you have an idea about the methods to replace the inf and nana values on the output values?

Comment: @oubo21 You didn't mention anything about what signals you have, what functions, what conditions. You have to realize that what goes on in your head, and what you're saying out loud, are two different things. Nobody can read minds. If you're wondering why you got downvotes, that's the reason: you didn't describe what you need, what you have, how are you using it, what you expect, what and how it went wrong. Only that you got bad numbers. Then, all of a sudden, you're mentioning filtering (which, BTW, it's `lfilter`, not "lfiltred").